# container startup issue for k8 for kafka & zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-desktop

i am trying to create a spring boot producer and consumer with
k8 zoo keeper & kafka but not able to set the k8 deployment its
failing  Not sure what is wrong configured here
becoz same things is working for me in docker compose

i have used the below file for creating the service and
deployment in local docker-desktop
kubectl apply -f $(pwd)/kubernates/sample.yml

and the error which i am getting at the time of the deployment
i have added at the last

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
  labels:
    app: zookeeper
spec:
  ports:
    - name: client
      port: 2181
      protocol: TCP
    - name: follower
      port: 2888
      protocol: TCP
    - name: leader
      port: 3888
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: zookeeper
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zoo1
          image: digitalwonderland/zookeeper
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
          env:
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1
              value: zookeeper
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka
  labels:
    name: kafka
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9092
      name: kafka-port
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: kafka
    id: "0"
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
        id: "0"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka
          image: wurstmeister/kafka
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
              value: "9092"
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
              value: kafka
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: zookeeper:2181
            - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
              value: "0"
            - name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
              value: sample.topic:1:1
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-cat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-cat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka-cat
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka-cat
          image: confluentinc/cp-kafkacat
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args: ["-c", "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"]**
```

exception in container

```
**[2020-08-03 18:47:49,724] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value tcp://10.103.92.112:9092 for configuration port: Not a number of type INT
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:726)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:474)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:467)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:142)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1235)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1238)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:1218)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:34)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:29)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:68)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

Answer (score 1):

finally i was able to solve this using different name for the kafka

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
  labels:
    app: zookeeper
spec:
  selector:
    app: zookeeper
  ports:
    - name: client
      port: 2181
      protocol: TCP
    - name: follower
      port: 2888
      protocol: TCP
    - name: leader
      port: 3888
      protocol: TCP

---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zookeeper
          image: digitalwonderland/zookeeper
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
          env:
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1
              value: zookeeper

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service0
  labels:
    name: kafka
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9092
      name: kafka-port
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: kafka
    id: "0"

---

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-broker0
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
        id: "0"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka
          image: wurstmeister/kafka
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: application-conf
                  key: kafka_ad_port
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: application-conf
                  key: zk_url
            - name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: application-conf
                  key: kafka_topic
            - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
              value: "0"
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
              value: kafka-service0
```

Comment: Error: configmap "application-conf" not found...... applied the above, facing this error

Comment: @muhammadshahan create a configuration in k8 first before executing the above file

Answer (score 1):

Rename Kubernetes service name from `kafka` to something else `kafka-broker` for example. Update `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` or `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` or both:

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka-broker:9092
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka-broker:9092
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: application-conf           # name of ConfigMap, referenced in other files
  namespace: default
data:
  host: "mysql"            # host address of mysql server, we are using DNS of Service
  name: "espark-mysql"    # name of the database for application
  port: "3306"
  zk_url: "zookeeper:2181"
  kafka_url: "kafka-service0:9092"
  kafka_topic: "espark-topic:1:2"
  kafka_ad_port: "9092"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the hostname and IP for `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` like (`localhost:9092`) in your YAML file for Kafka.